# Making calls programmatically in Samsung Devices in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a call using the following code:

```
String phoneNumber = unItemVal.getText().toString();
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Call is getting initiated using Nexus 5 but when I try the same code on Samsung device it doesn't do anything.

What is the difference between Nexus 5 and Samsung Devices?

Thanks!

Comment: did you have the permission `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` ?

Comment: first of all: what versions android are you running on each device?  is your code updated for correct version of android on each device?

Comment: Yeah, because can be the newer permissions that are not allowed to your application. good point @tonygil

Comment: Also, what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. As I said call feature is working fine on Nexus 5 which is running Marshmellow. I have all required permission for M and call_phone in manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

Try using [Action.PHONE_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) instead. (In your code, replace `ACTION_CALL` with `ACTION_DIAL`).

[Action.PHONE_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) is not guaranteed to work for all apps. Quoting from the Javadoc:

```
Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.

Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.
```